# How to remove white space from Header?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I have hidden action bar and using simple title [made using Linear layout] instead of action bar, 

In some devices i am getting white space before title as i marked with red line in attached image.

Its working fine with 240x320, 320x480, 480x800 dpi.

Can any body has some idea how to remove this white spacing before Title ?
Please suggest some idea.

[image]

Edited: Root Element tag code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="?page_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Edited 2: page background style

```
 <style name="page_background">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: I think thereis some padding in the root layout. Specify android:padding="0dp" for your root layout. I think, that HTC (with sense) may have some padding in default theme.

Comment: I did not specify any padding in my code, as i edited my question.

Comment: I see. And you say that on some device you have padding but on other not. That's why I think that there is some default value for padding on some device. HTC, Samsung and other like rewrite default theme and you can find some interesting behavior by default. Specify padding="0dp" to be sure, that there is no default value for padding.

Comment: And also share your ?page_background style.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i edited my question for page background style.

Comment: Hm, it's very strange. Can you post the whole layout?